# Missing method declaration in view controller

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have typed this into my .m file - `StudentLoginViewController` - and the compiler keeps giving me the error:

> no visible @interface for 'NOSbject' declares the selector 'viewDidLoad'

Here's my code:

```
// StudentLoginViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface StudentLoginViewController : NSObject  <UITextFieldDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UILabel *Username ,*Password ;
    IBOutlet UIButton *LoginButton ;
    IBOutlet UITextField *UsernameText ,*PasswordText;
}

@end

// StudentLoginViewController.m

#import "StudentLoginViewController.h"

@interface StudentLoginViewController ()

@end

@implementation StudentLoginViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UsernameText.delegate=self;
    PasswordText.delegate=self;
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    // this text will not be updated to the newest text yet,
    // but we know what what the user just did to get into a string

    NSString *Username, *Password;
    if (textField == UsernameText) {
        Username = @"jzarate";
        Password = PasswordText.text; 
    } else {
        Username= UsernameText.text;
        Password = @"14054";
    }

    // If both the username and password are correct  then enable the button
    LoginButton.enabled = ([Username isEqualToString:@"jzarate"] && [Password isEqualToString:@"14054"]);

    // return YES so that the users edits  are used
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Please note that the code above for the .m file is all the code in it, I have removed the other bits above and below this.

Comment: This has **absolutely *nothing*** to do with Xcode nor with the `if` statement.

Comment: What prompted your choice of `NSObject` for the superclass?

Comment: i didnt prompt it, it did it by itself when i went t play it on the IOS IPhone6.1 generator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `viewDidLoad` is invoked when you will inherit `StudentLoginViewController` from `UIViewController` instead of NSObject. NSObject is itself a super Class of all, so it does not have any parent, who declares viewDidLoad. So you are getting error at:

`[super viewDidLoad];`

Write:

`@interface StudentLoginViewController : UIViewController  <UITextFieldDelegate>`

instead of

`@interface StudentLoginViewController : NSObject  <UITextFieldDelegate>`

Comment: @AnumAmin Who says you can't use IBOutlets with NSObject?  Go into IB and search for NSObject, then drag one in and see for yourself.